# Promise Catch is not receiving error in json rpc calls

Tags: node.js, rest, api, promise, grpc

I am trying to get error if the address is wrong or transactions is not successfull but not getting any response. Please help me out

/*LIST TRANSACTIONS API*/

```
app.post('/sendtoadd',(req,res) => {

        var fromAdd = req.body.fromAddress;
        var toAdd = req.body.toAddress;
        var qty= req.body.qty;
        var assetId = req.body.assetId;
        console.log("SEND TO ADDRESS API is in progress");
        functions.sendToAddress(fromAdd, toAdd, qty, assetId).then(function(result){
            res.send(result);
        }).catch(function(err){ 
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        });
})
```

/*Function Definition  */

```
function sendToAddress(fromAddress, toAddress, qty, assetId){
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            var client = new rpc.Client(options);
            client.call({
                "jsonrpc":"2.0", 
                "id":1, 
                "method":"sendtoaddress", 
                "params":[fromAddress,toAddress,qty,assetId]
                },
                function (err, res){
                    if(err){
                        reject(err);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        var msg = res;
                        var message = msg.result;
                        resolve(message);
                    }
                })
        })
}
```

Comment: And how can I check the response message if the error is in the json response

Comment: You tagged this with [grpc]. Can you clarify what gRPC library you are using and how you are creating or loading the `rpc.Client` class?

Answer (score 0):

client.call 's callback function is Asynchronous. hence it would not find the reject() or resolve() callback.

try:

```
function sendToAddress(fromAddress, toAddress, qty, assetId){

    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var res = resolve,
            rej = reject;
        var client = new rpc.Client(options);
        client.call({
            "jsonrpc":"2.0", 
            "id":1, 
            "method":"sendtoaddress", 
            "params":[fromAddress,toAddress,qty,assetId]
        },
        function (err, res){
            if(err){
                rej(err);
                return;
            } else {
                var msg = res;
                var message = msg.result;
                res(message);
            }
        })
    });
}
```